# Sklearn error cannot reshape array of size 6912 into shape (614,154)

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, sklearn-pandas

I watched this video on how to build your first neural network but got stuck with this error at 27:00 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6912 into shape (614,154)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2sZNlr-4_4

The code is below:

```py
# This algorithm detects if a person has diabetes or not

# Load libraries
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd
# load data
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
# Store the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('datasets_4511_6897_diabetes.csv')
# convert the data into an array
dataset = df.values
# get all of the rows from the first eight columns of the dataset
X = dataset[:,0:8]
y = dataset[:,8]
# process the data
from sklearn import preprocessing 
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)

# split the data into 80% training and 20% testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scale, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)
# build the model

model = Sequential([
    Dense(12, activation ='relu', input_shape = (8,)),
    Dense(15, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
#Compile the model (sgd = stochastic gradient descent)

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'sgd',
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
# train the model

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 57, epochs = 1000, validation_split=0.2)
# evaluate the model on the training data set
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

pred = model.predict(X_train)
pred = [1 if y >= 0.5 else 0 for y in prediction]
#df = df.values.reshape(614,154)
print('confusion_matrix : /n', confusion_matrix(y_train, pred))
```

Do you have an idea on how to deal with this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to give a little more context on what is the aim of that reshape. It seems very unclear as for now what you'd need that reshape there in your code, which is unused since after that you're just looking at the confusion matrix.
With what you've shared, `df` is a Series of shape `6912`, which you're trying to reshape to `(614,154)`, which cannot be done, since `614*154=94556`.

Comment: HI Yatu, thanks for your feedback, I am new to python I think that the aim of that reshape is the /one of the condition(s) to plot a confusion matrix. Can you explain me where those the numbers 614 and 154 come from?

Comment: But that's the problem, with no more context i have not idea :)  You don't need df at all for the cf though, just pred and y_train

Comment: The context is to detect if a person has diabetes or not, the data are extracted from a CSV. After training the neural network my second objective was to evaluate the model on the training dataset first and the testing dataset secondly.

Comment: 614 and 154 are the y_train and y_test shape, respectively

Comment: Right. Then that reshape makes no sense. Also, why do you need it, you're not using it at all in the confusion matrix function

Comment: This is why I put the reshape code line in commentary. However I still have the same error.

Comment: In the confusion matrix, you need pred and y_test. Not y_train

Comment: Does it lean that I cannot evaluate the model on the training dataset but only on the testing dataset? And does it lean that I also to modify the code line : pred = model.predict(X_train) to pred = model.predict(X_test)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't predict on the training set... That's what the test is for. That is very basic in ml, I suggest you to read about that before attempting anything more complex or running your own models

Comment: Can you recommend me good resources for beginners?

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/ is probably a good start